# Set "enctype" attribute to "application/json"

Tags: jquery, http, forms, http-post

Here is my code for making POST request:

```
function post(path, params, method) {
  method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

  // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
  // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.setAttribute("method", method);
  form.setAttribute("action", path);
  form.setAttribute("enctype", "application/json");
  for(var key in params) {
    if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
      hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
      hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

      form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }
  }

  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
}
```

I tried to set the `Content-type` in HTTP header to "application/json" by setting `enctype` of the form to "application/json". However, it doesn't work.

I saw an [unofficial draft](https://darobin.github.io/formic/specs/json/) about supporting "application/json" for `enctype` however it seems not accepted yet..

Does anyone have ideas about how to make a POST request and use `JSON` instead of `formdata` as the data format without resorting to AJAX?

Comment: It looks like the actual values from the DOM that is used for the HTTP header is the `HTMLFormElement.encoding` object property, which will revert to one of the three allowed values even if directly changed, per the HTML 5 spec : http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-fs-encoding

Comment: So it's not a matter of "can it be done" so much as "even if you try, will the browser ignore your attempts", which it does, it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone have ideas about how to make a POST request and use JSON instead of formdata as the data format without resorting to AJAX?

There is no way to do this. Work on [JSON as a form encoding type](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/) has been abandoned.

If you are writing an HTTP endpoint that expects normal form submissions, write it so it accepts `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` encoded data.

Those are [the only encoding types that browsers support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype) for form submissions (other than `text/plain` which isn't suitable for machine processing).

The only way to send a JSON payload is with Ajax, which you rejected as an option.

Comment: Quentin, I wonder that, If we cant change data type by enctype, Why they needed it? I confused. I faced same problem and I did not solve it too. Is not there any way to post data as application/json?

Comment: You can change the encoding of the data using `enctype`. You just can't change it to encodings that the browser doesn't know about.